# Iterating through an arralist - java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

```
public void display(detailTom tomData)
{
   ArrayList<detailTom> temp = new ArrayList<detailTom>();

  for (int i=0;i<tomData.toString().length();i++)
  {
      temp=tomData[i];
      System.out.println(temp.getMark1());
  }


}
```

Hello all,

I am trying to iterate through an arraylist tomData which is an object arraylist. I am trying to iterate through the list and display the variable of the object "Mark1".

The error is get is "Array required but detailTom found"

any ideas? Or any other way of iterating through tomData?

Comment: What do you think `tomData[i];` does and why?

Comment: And why are you using the length of some string representation of `tomData` to work out how far to iterate? And where do you think the `getMark1` method is declared? (Hint: it's not on `ArrayList`...)

Comment: You defined `tomdata` as a `detailTom` which is not an array, so you can't access it as if it were an array.

Comment: Basically, think about the types of *all* these expressions. (And ideally name your classes in `PascalCase` too...)

Comment: the main object of tomData[i] is to pass the object to temp so that temp can display the value

Comment: None of the lines of code make any sense (except the ones with `}`)  You can't program based on what you meant the code to do.  Can you show us what code you have which compiles at least.

Comment: You have defined `temp` as an ArrayList and ArrayList doesn't have a method called `getMark1()`.  `temp` doesn't appear to have any purpose.

Comment: public void display(detailTom tomData) is a method to display the contents of tomData which is an arraylist of objects of class detailTom

Comment: detailTom is a class which has variables and getters and setters

Comment: In which case, surely you want the signature to be `public void display(List<detailTom> tomData)`, since `tomData` is a `List` of instances of class `detailTom`?

Comment: let me try that Edd - thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've provided doesn't really make sense, but based on the comments I'm guessing the answer you're looking for is something like the following:

```
public void display(List<DetailTom> tomData) {
    for (DetailTom detail : tomData) {
        System.out.println(detail.getMk1());
    }
}
```

I've renamed your class from `detailTom` to `DetailTom` as is the [convention in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#d5e6518):

> Names of class types should be descriptive nouns or noun phrases, not overly long, in mixed case with the first letter of each word capitalized.

Comment: thanks Edd - that worked. The problem I had with my code is as follows:-

Comment: My method was declared initially as - public void display(detailTom tomData). I should have declared it as public void display(ArrayList<detailTom> tomData)